# Struts2 - The requested list key 'Products' could not be resolved

Tags: struts2

I am new to Struts 2 and trying to see whether I can populate a drop down box with the list of values but still I am not able to get it working.

Following is my Action class (Portal.java):

```
public class Portal extends ActionSupport {

    private Map Products;
    private String product;

    public Portal(){
       Products = new HashMap();
       Products.put("1", "Java");
       Products.put("2", "C++");
    }

    public Map getProducts() {  
       return Products;
    }


    public void setProducts(Map Products) {
       this.Products = Products;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
    return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
    }  

    public String execute() {
       return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Following is my Portal.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Portal</h2>
<s:form action="result" namespace="/">
    <h4>
        <s:select label="Select Product"
        name="product"
        headerKey="-1"
        headerValue="Select Product"            
        list="Products"                                                     
        />
    </h4>
    <h4>
        <s:submit label="Submit" name="submitButton"  align="center" />
    </h4>
</s:form>
```

Following is my result.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Results Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Portal</h1> 
<h4>
   Selected Product : <s:property value="product"/>
</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="false" />
   <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">          
      <action name="result" class="com.abc.xyz.Portal">
         <result name="error">Portal.jsp</result>
         <result name="success">Result.jsp</result>                     
      </action>     
   </package>
</struts>
```

Following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Portal</display-name>
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>Portal.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I execute this on Tomcat 6 server, I get following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'product': The requested list key 'Products' could   
not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: 
people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

But when I replace list="Products" with list="#{'1':'Java', '2':'C++'}", then it works perfectly fine .. I don't know what am I missing so that the list is not being shown.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Memory is not allocated for Map Products.

Just before setting the values for the Products write - 
Products = new Map();

then set the values to the map. This will help to populate the values of the Products on the View.

Answer (score 2):

Java is case sensitive... **list="products"** is what you want not **list="Products"**

**Edit**: see the comments under this question, you should have a getter or change the access to Products to public.

Comment: No, He was defined Products as reference variable.

Comment: Reference variable? I didn't read the question that carefully but looking at it again... The variable Products in the action class should be "products" and there should be a getter for it, which there is not.

Answer (score 1):

According to Struts2 data prepopulation should be done by [PreparableInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/prepare-interceptor.html) and you have to override prepare method.

```
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    Products = new HashMap();
    Products.put("1", "C#");
    Products.put("2", "Java");

}
```

Comment: prepare method is used if you want to prepare some data before execute() method get called by framework.Prepare method can be related to init() method.

Comment: What init() method you are referring to?

Comment: i am talking about a method which is like a constructor, which is responsible to preparing things for you before actual piece of code will start its main work.

Comment: Yes agreed, then what is the purpose prepare interceptor.

Comment: what i described is the purpose of this interceptor, please go through the doc for more details

Comment: Can I use constructor to pre-populate the list/map?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you open your  Portal.jsp it look on valuestack but it didn't get that's why this error come.Because on load the corresponding action is not calling,you have to call action onload.Implement Preparable interface and override the prepare method and in that method you write your code.``

Answer (score 0):

Refer my answer to this similar question: [Struts2 list couldn't be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609752/struts2-list-couldnt-be-resolved/31675126)

For additional details refer:
https://struts.apache.org/docs/message-resource-files.html