# Struts2 issue while loading the s:select list

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Strut2 : Exception occurred during processing request: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'abc': The requested list key 'xyz' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration type.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ABC" class="col-md-3 control-label">
                ABC: </label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <s:select name="abc"
                    list="xyz"
                    id="abc" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the JSP code

In Java class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Test extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

private List xyz = new ArrayList<String>();

public List getXyz() {
    return xyz;
}


public void setXyz(List xyz) {
    this.xyz = xyz;
}

@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Database connectivity and fetch data from DB and adding that data to 
        xyz
    }

}
```

and in the java class's constructor I am trying to populate the list from the database.

Comment: why is your setter for xyz setting a string into List?

Comment: sorry my bad, edited

Comment: try changing to private List xyz = new ArrayList(); 
It looks like the list item is being accessed before the class is initialized.

Also refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609752/struts2-list-couldnt-be-resolved

Comment: The action class constructor is not the right place to populate the list. Do it in the action method or in prepare method.

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried doing that as well, but didn't work

Comment: @AleksandrM Have updated the question

Comment: Remove `new ArrayList<String>()` part.

Comment: @AleksandrM removed, still doesn't work

Comment: Are sure that `xyz` is populated in the method? Also is `xyz` actual name that you use?

Comment: @AleksandrM I am sure xyz is being used. No, 'xyz' is not the actual name that I am using.

Comment: Does your real `xyz` starts with single lower case letter?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes it does start with a lower case

Comment: @ChinmayGhag https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration#Struts2.3to2.5migration-Fieldnames